# Setting the value of a drop down list from a record that is selected

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, drop-down-menu

I am using AngularJS and I need to set a selected option of a drop-down list control when a record is selected for editing and loaded to a form. The dropdown should still have the other values available if the user wants to select a different one.

When there is no record selected, the form should still have the list of values available if the user wants to create a new record.

Down below is the screen shot of my form when it first loads. You can see in the screen shot that the Instruments drop-down-list shows all the instruments available. This list is loaded through a web service that is called when the form loads.

It puts all the contents into an array named: $scope.instruments

Code:

```
  //Get Instruments
  $http.get('/api/Instrument/GetAllInstruments').success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
      $scope.instruments = data;
  }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
      $scope.error = "An error has occurred while fetching Instruments." + data;
  });
```

[image]

Below the form, there is a grid with all the records:

[image]

When a user clicks on the edit icon, the record loads on the form:

[image]

The record has values for the instrument, style, and scoring but I do not know how to use those values from the record, to set the selected value on the drop down.

This is the code that I am using to load the selected record and assign instrument id, style id, scoring id. Is not the most elegant code, but this is as far as I have been able to get:

```
      //Edit Store Page
  $scope.edit = function () {

      if (this.page.SPPreambleID === null || this.page.SPPreambleID === 0)
      {
          this.page.SPPreambleID = -1;
      }

      $http.get('/api/StorePage/GetStorePage?StorePageID=' + this.page.StorePageID + '&SPPreambleID=' + this.page.SPPreambleID).success(function (data) {

          $scope.updateShow = true;
          $scope.addShow = false;              

          $scope.newpage = data;

          angular.forEach($scope.newpage.SPAttributeRefID, function (attribute, index) {

              if (attribute == 1) {
                  $scope.recordInstrument = $scope.newpage.AttributeID[0];                      
              }

              if (attribute == 2) {
                  $scope.recordStyle = $scope.newpage.AttributeID[1];
              }

              if (attribute == 3) {
                  $scope.recordScoring = $scope.newpage.AttributeID[2];
              }
          });


      }).error(function () {
          $scope.error = "An Error has occured while Editing this Store Page!" + data;
      });
  }
```

And this is the HTML for the drop downs:

```
                @* Instrument *@
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-10 space">
                        <select class="form-control" name="instrumentfilter" data-ng-model="instrumentfilter" required
                            data-ng-options="i.ID as i.Description for i in instruments track by i.ID" data-ng-change="">
                            <option value="">-- Choose a Style --</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>


                @* Style *@
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-10 space">
                        <select class="form-control" name="stylefilter" data-ng-model="stylefilter" required
                            data-ng-options="st.ID as st.Description for st in styles track by st.ID" data-ng-change="">
                            <option value="">-- Choose a Style --</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>

                @* Scoring *@
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-10 space">
                        <select class="form-control" name="scoringfilter" data-ng-model="scoringfilter" required
                            data-ng-options="sc.ID as sc.Description for sc in scorings track by sc.ID">
                            <option value="">-- Choose a Scoring --</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Please any help I can get in this forum would be great. I have been struggling with this all day, and I am sure it should not be too complicated.

**Update**

This is the updated HTML after recommendation to modified data-ng-model to use the scope variables recordInstrument, recordStyle, and recordScoring.

```
                @* Instrument *@
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-10 space">
                        <select class="form-control" name="instrumentfilter" data-ng-model="recordInstrument" required
                            data-ng-options="i.ID as i.Description for i in instruments track by i.ID" data-ng-change="">
                            <option value="">-- Choose a Style --</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>


                @* Style *@
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-10 space">
                        <select class="form-control" name="stylefilter" data-ng-model="recordStyle" required
                            data-ng-options="st.ID as st.Description for st in styles track by st.ID" data-ng-change="">
                            <option value="">-- Choose a Style --</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming that JS code

```
angular.forEach($scope.newpage.SPAttributeRefID, function (attribute, index) {

          if (attribute == 1) {
              $scope.recordInstrument = getRecordInstrument($scope.newpage.AttributeID[0]);                      
          }

          if (attribute == 2) {
              $scope.recordStyle = getRecordStyle($scope.newpage.AttributeID[1]);
          }

          if (attribute == 3) {
              $scope.recordScoring = getRecordScoring($scope.newpage.AttributeID[2]);
          }
      });
```

get correct IDs, and there are 3 functions *getRecordInstrument*, *getRecordStyle* and *getRecordScoring* which fetch *instrument*, *style* or *scoring* objects by its ID, try to assign these IDs to selects via *ngModel* directive:

```
            @* Style *@
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-10 space">
                    <select class="form-control" name="instrumentfilter" data-ng-model="recordInstrument" required
                        data-ng-options="i.ID as i.Description for i in instruments track by i.ID">
                        <option value="">-- Choose a Style --</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>


            @* Style *@
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-10 space">
                    <select class="form-control" name="stylefilter" data-ng-model="recordStyle" required
                        data-ng-options="st.ID as st.Description for st in styles track by st.ID">
                        <option value="">-- Choose a Style --</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>

            @* Scoring *@
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-10 space">
                    <select class="form-control" name="scoringfilter" data-ng-model="recordScoring" required
                        data-ng-options="sc.ID as sc.Description for sc in scorings track by sc.ID">
                        <option value="">-- Choose a Scoring --</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: When I click a record to edit, the IDs are assigned correctly, that is: recordInstrument = 506 which is keyboards, recordStyle = 183 which is Acid Jzz, and recordScoring = 45 which is orchestra. The record loads on every field, but I do not see the variables just mentioned, being used to set the drop-downs to those IDs. Nothing happens and I do not see an error either.

Comment: did you update your HTML to use correct ngModels? for example: data-ng-model="recordScoring", this scope variable should update your select box correctly. See my answer and make sure you modified 3 data-ng-model's in your HTML

Comment: please upload your code to plunker or something, so I can see what is wrong there and hopefully solve it. Also make sure that you have ID value that you assign to scope in your select options

Comment: Thank you for your help. I uploaded the code to jsfiddle, but is really not doing anything. I just uploaded so that you can see the entire js.
https://jsfiddle.net/itortu/sd7hzp38/
The code you want to see is under the //Edit Store Page section. and possibly the //GetInstruments section too.

Comment: sorry, you should assign you scope variables not just ID, but entire object, I updated my answer, and created a small plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/E4D9hRmujc5meQzmnvEx?p=preview, demonstrating similar select

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125216/discussion-between-erasmo-carlos-and-andriy).

Comment: Hi Andriy, I tried to follow your example, it is clear what I have to do, the problem I ran into is that your #scope.instruments is structured differently than my $scope.instruments, so I get undefined when trying to do:  $scope.instruments[data.AttributeID[0]] ;
I added all the details in the discussion chat. Are you able to see those?

Comment: Hi Andriy, last night i did some reading and tried to use reduce to 'flatten' the $scope.instruments array, but i was tired and was not able to make it work. i am going to plug in your code and i hope to do it right, i will post an update either way. i will do it in the question and not chat if you prefer. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I implemented your code. Still even though I can see the correct ID being assigned to $scope.recordInstrument, the dropdown list does not reflect that selection, it remains with the default option value of: "Choose an Instrument". Within the angular.forEach loop, this is what I did for the instruments: if (attribute == 1) { $scope.instruments = $scope.instruments.reduce(function (result, instrument) { result[instrument.ID] = instrument; return result }, {}); $scope.recordInstrument = $scope.instruments[$scope.newpage.AttributeID[0]].ID;}

Comment: After the if gets met, and the forEach loop exists the value of $scope.recordInstrument is 506, but the option of the drop down list remains unchanged.

Comment: the html still the same: <select class="form-control" name="instrumentfilter" ng-model="recordInstrument" required data-ng-options="i.ID as i.Description for i in instruments track by i.ID"><option value="">-- Choose a Instrument --</option></select>

Comment: I got it to work. I had to remove the part:  track by i.ID form the html

Comment: Hi Andriy, if I select a record that has an instrument, style, and scoring assigned, I am loading the values to the drop down. How can I if I go from a record that has values, to a record that does not have values for the same attributes, reset the drop-downs?

Comment: When I click more than one record to load on the form, then I get an error: $scope.instruments.reduce is not a function

Comment: you should convert $scope.instruments array to object only once, at the beginning of your controller (see my updated plunker - http://plnkr.co/edit/E4D9hRmujc5meQzmnvEx?p=preview), for example. reduce() is Array's function not Object's, so make sure you run it only once on $scope.instruments as array. I did not understand your previous question, for being properly displayed in the select box, instrument has to have only ID and description attributes.

Comment: Code is working and I am very thankful for having received so much help from you Andriy. Thank you very much.